# seting TextView's dynamically?

Tags: android

i'm trying to create a program, but getting an error although it is runnable but force stops when i click the button, here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected static final Object[][] tv = null;
    Integer time[] = { 0, 1 };
    String days[] = { "a", "b" };
    TextView tv00, tv10, tv01, tv11;
    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tv00 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int x = 0; x < time.length; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < days.length; y++) {
                        ((TextView) tv[x][y]).setText("ch" + time[x] + days[y]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

here is the logcat

> 09-21 13:06:13.414: D/AndroidRuntime(282): Shutting down VM
>
> 09-21 13:06:13.414: W/dalvikvm(282): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
>
> 09-21 13:06:13.434: E/AndroidRuntime(282): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 09-21 13:06:13.434: E/AndroidRuntime(282):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 09-21 13:06:13.434: E/AndroidRuntime(282):    at
>   com.thesis.testing.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
>
> 09-21 13:06:13.434: E/AndroidRuntime(282):    at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
>
> 09-21 13:06:13.434: E/AndroidRuntime(282):    at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
>
> 09-21 13:06:13.434: E/AndroidRuntime(282):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>
> 09-21 13:06:13.434: E/AndroidRuntime(282):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>
> 09-21 13:06:13.434: E/AndroidRuntime(282):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> 09-21 13:06:13.434: E/AndroidRuntime(282):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>
> 09-21 13:06:13.434: E/AndroidRuntime(282):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 09-21 13:06:13.434: E/AndroidRuntime(282):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>
> 09-21 13:06:13.434: E/AndroidRuntime(282):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>
> 09-21 13:06:13.434: E/AndroidRuntime(282):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>
> 09-21 13:06:13.434: E/AndroidRuntime(282):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 09-21 13:06:15.944: I/Process(282): Sending signal. PID: 282 SIG: 9
>   v22.3.0-887826

if you want to know whats in the layout xml, its just 4 Textviews and a Button just as listed here.

also, im trying to make in into ((TextView tv+time[x]+date[y].setText..... if possible.

any help would be great.

Comment: where you initialize `tv` in your code? indicate line 33 on `MainActivity.java` class too

Comment: there's no initialized for tv, but it was supposed to be, ex. tv[x][y] which i thought would mean to tv00(for the line 13)

Comment: you can't do that, if you want do this you must initialize your array and put `TextView`s on array then use that,

Answer (score -1):

You never initialize tv.  Simplest thing to do is make both days and time static.

Then you can do something like:

```
static Integer time[] = { 0, 1 };
static String days[] = { "a", "b" };
protected static final Object[][] tv = new Object[time.length][days.length];
```

Then populate your tv array with your TextViews before using it.

```
tv[0] = tv00;
tv[1] = tv10;
tv[2] = tv01;
tv[3] = tv11;
```

Comment: hmmm. can you please provide the revised codes> im still new in adnroid, so i really understand everything for now.

Comment: `tv` shouldn't be static - it should be changed to be an instance variable. There is no purpose to making any of this code static as it is localised to this activity.

Comment: Andrew, I didn't think it was right or necessary to write the code for him, but instead to give him enough information to continue past the obvious mistake.

Comment: @MichaelKrause i can see your point, but im really just started. i can see where i must delete/add(i think) those codes, i just want to do it correct, if that's ok with you.

Comment: @MichaelKrause it's the quicker fix to remove a single static than add two more, and its reinforcing much better coding standards

Comment: it errors at the initialization. is something im doing wrong?